# Identify a component

Tags: pcb, components, identification

Could you please help me out here. What would this component be? It's marked YA.[image]
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the circuit, it appears to be a transistor.  By using a DMM in diode test mode you might be able to determine if it NPN, PNP or shorted or measure voltages when active.

Not listed [here](http://www.marsport.org.uk/smd/smdy.htm)

But possibly a PNP [here](http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/ya)